# Por que devemos usar "IS NOT NULL" ao invés de "<> NULL"?

Tags: mysql, query, null

Sempre me perguntei isso: Por que devemos usar `IS NOT NULL` ao invés de `<> NULL`?
Pois, quando faço como no segundo caso, nenhum resultado é encontrado.

Exemplo:

```
SELECT * FROM tabela WHERE campo IS NOT NULL
```

Exibe todas as linhas, exceto quando `campo` não é nulo.

Exemplo:

```
SELECT * FROM tabela WHERE campo <> NULL
```

Não exibe nada.

**Observação**: A primeira vez que tentei fazer essa comparação foi com `!=` e também não deu certo. Pois a funcionalidade desses operadores são semelhantes.

Comment: A SQL entende que `null` não pode ser comparado e `<>` é operador de comparação. A comparação de um valor com `null` resulta em "desconhecido", daí o resultado não ser o que você espera. Conforme o que está sendo comparado com `null` ou o tipo esperado para o resultado da comparação, o banco terá um comportamento específico. O jeito certo (padrão ANSI SQL) para verificar se um campo é nulo é `is null` (ou `is not null` para negação).

Comment: já vi gente tentanto fazer != NULL, mas com <> foi a primeira vez...rsrsrsr

Comment: @SneepSNinjA Não entendi. Ambos os operadores (`!=` e `<>`) são suportados pelo MySql e creio que `<>` seja o padrão ANSI SQL.

Comment: Estou dizendo que a primeira vez na vida que tentei fazer essa consulta (da questão) eu fiz assim: `SELECT * FROM teste WHERE x != NULL`; e deu errado. A pergunta foi no sentido de saber porque essa comparação não funciona e a do `NOT NULL` funciona

Comment: @Caffé o operador equivalente para comparar o NULL seria assim *coluna* <=> NULL e nao <> NULL da uma lida ai http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/comparison-operators.html

Comment: Engraçado isso @SneepSNinjA! Como algo pode ser `<=>` (menor ou igual ou maior) ?

Comment: *opa para ser igual a NULL é <=> http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_equal-to

Comment: para buscar os não nulos teria que gambiarrar mesmo tipo NOT ( coluna <=> NULL);

Comment: @SneepSNinjA O que eu não entendi foi a parte divertida de tentar '<>' para testar se a coluna é "diferente de", já que este é um operador comum para este teste. De qualquer modo, o `<=>` (recurso especial do MySql) não é o mesmo que `IS NOT NULL`.

Comment: @Caffé quando filtramos assim `coluna <> null` ou assim `coluna != null` não da o mesmo resultado que `coluna is not null`, pelo menos não no MySql

Comment: @SneepSNinjA Sim, está lá no meu primeiro comentário nessa pergunta :-) Creio que atualmente `coluna <> null` não funcione em nenhum banco.

Comment: @Caffé... rsrsrsr então a parte 'divertida' é que eu nunca tinha vista alguém tentar buscar valores 'não nulos' desse jeito `<> null` só isso :D

Comment: Relacionado: [Porque valores NULL não são selecionados?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/87514/porque-valores-null-n%C3%A3o-s%C3%A3o-selecionados)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Você não pode utilizar operadores de comparação aritméticos para validar o 
`NULL` pois eles sempre retornarão `NULL`. Para verificar um valor `NULL` utilize aos operadores `IS NULL` e `IS NOT NULL`.

Um exemplo:

```
mysql> SELECT 1 = NULL, 1 <> NULL, 1 < NULL, 1 > NULL;
+----------+-----------+----------+----------+
| 1 = NULL | 1 <> NULL | 1 < NULL | 1 > NULL |
+----------+-----------+----------+----------+
|     NULL |      NULL |     NULL |     NULL |
+----------+-----------+----------+----------+
```

No  MySQL o 0(zero) e `NULL` são considerados como `FALSE`, e todo o restante como `TRUE`. O valor default para `TRUE` é `1`.

```
mysql> SELECT 1 IS NULL, 1 IS NOT NULL;
+-----------+---------------+
| 1 IS NULL | 1 IS NOT NULL |
+-----------+---------------+
|         0 |             1 |
+-----------+---------------+
```

Dica de leitura: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/working-with-null.html