# Por que valores NULL não são selecionados?

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, sql-server, null, sqlfiddle

Ao fazer um select, reparei que os dados com campo `NULL` não são recuperados usando o operador`<>`.

- Por que isso acontece?
- `NULL` é igual a um `char N`?

Vejam que na consulta abaixo só a primeira linha é retornada.

## [SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d1b63/1)

Comment: `null` é ausência de valor, precisa usar, algo como `select * from where coluna is null`

Comment: Como disse o @rray, `NULL` é a ausência de valor, e `<>` compara com valores, por isso não vem a linha com `NULL`.

Comment: Se bem me lembro a ausência ou presença do NULL só pode ser testada usando "IS NOT NULL" ou "IS NULL". Comparações normais não funcionam. É mais ou menos como o NaN do ponto flutuante, que é diferente de qualquer número, até dele mesmo.

Comment: [Quando devemos permitir que uma coluna de uma tabela de um banco de dados aceite NULL?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2296/91)

Comment: **Leitura recomendada:** http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/90363/o-que-realmente-significa-null/90378#90378

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`NULL` é `NULL`, ele não se compara (em condições normais) com outras coisas. Sua seleção está pegando *todos os dados **não nulos** que sejam diferentes de `N`*.

Para incluir os nulos a consulta deve dizer isto explicitamente.

```
select * from Exemplo where texto <> 'N' or texto is null
```

Veja [funcionando no **SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/d1b63/1). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Select/Nulls.sql).

Neste caso você está pedindo *todos os dados que sejam diferentes de `N` incluindo os valores desconhecidos*

Para usar a terminologia correta, nulo é o **valor desconhecido**. Não quer dizer que não tem valor. Tem sim, o valor é nulo, só que ele é tratado de forma especial. A confusão gerada é um dos motivos de alguns programadores considerarem o nulo como algo ruim.

Answer (score 30):

Null não é uma string concreta, é valor nulo. Sendo assim o SQL não irá retornar valor, pois você perguntou:

> Retorna todos os registros que **contenham valor** DIFERENTE de N em minha tabela

Sendo assim o SQL SERVER irá retornar os registros que contenham valores verdadeiros no campo texto que sejam diferente de valor N, como por exemplo: `true`, `false`, `0`, `-1` ou `string`

Para contornar isso você poderá utilizar as expressões:

```
select * from Exemplo where texto <> 'N' OR texto IS NULL
```

ou você poderá converter null para um valor

```
select * from Exemplo where isnull(texto, -1) <> 'N'
```

Answer (score 24):

`Null` não é um valor. Como dito no [comentário](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/87514/null-%c3%a9-igual-a-n#comment176472_87514) do @rray, `null` é ausência de valor.

Seu `select` está trazendo todos os campos que **não sejam nulos** e que sejam diferentes de `N`.

Para incluir os nulos na sua consulta você precisa deixar isso explícito:

```
SELECT * FROM TABELA WHERE TEXTO <> 'N' OR TEXTO IS NULL
```

Para verificar se um campo é nulo em SQL você precisa fazer

```
SELECT * FROM TABELA WHERE CAMPO IS NULL
```

O mesmo vale para verificar se um campo tem algum valor, porém você usa o operador de negação `NOT`

```
SELECT * FROM TABELA WHERE CAMPO IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 15):

`null` é ausência de valor, precisa usar `IS NULL` para saber se a coluna possui ou não valor. São 3 valores, algo, vazio e ausência de valor(null).