# Sql Server 2014 Valor Null

Tags: sql, sql-server

Sou iniciante em Sql server, estou com dúvida em relação ao seguinte código:

```
declare @var nvarchar(50) = null

declare @bool bit

if (@var = null)
    set @bool = 1
else
    set @bool = 0

print @bool
```

A variável `@bool` retorna como `0`, mesmo eu declarando a variável `@var` como nulo.

Não seria para retornar como `1` ?

Comment: Veja: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/87514/null-%C3%A9-igual-a-n

Answer (score 7):

Esta é uma das sutilezas mais particulares de se trabalhar com banco de dados.

Isto:

```
if (@var = null) -- Preste atenção aqui
    set @bool = 1
else
    set @bool = 0
```

É diferente disto:

```
if (@var is null) -- Preste atenção aqui
    set @bool = 1
else
    set @bool = 0
```

A comparação `= null` em bancos de dados **sempre** será falsa. Isto porque `null` [é a ausência de valor](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/90363/o-que-realmente-significa-null/90378#90378), então não é comparável, diferentemente de verificar se o valor é `null`, o que faz o retorno ser `1`.

Answer (score 1):

Você não conseguirá compara um valor de um campo **null** com o operador **=**, para isso existe o `IS NULL` ou seja.

```
if (@var is null) 
    set @bool = 1
else
    set @bool = 0
```

Há uma coisa também que tem que se atentar sua variável @var ainda pode ter um valor Empty onde você poderia checar da seguinte forma.

```
IF (@var IS NOT NULL) OR (LEN(@var) > 0)
    set @bool = 1
else
    set @bool = 0
```

[Veja mais detalhes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12264602/how-do-check-if-a-parameter-is-empty-or-null-in-sql-server-stored-procedure-in-i).