# Qual a diferença de uma string vazia e NULL no SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-select, sql-insert, null

Qual a diferença de se armazenar uma `string` como `NULL` ou vazia no SQL?

Como esses dois podem se comportar quando eu for fazer um `SELECT`, ou `INSERT` com valor `''` nessa coluna que é do tipo `varchar`?

Se eu deixar o valor predefinido como `None`, não consigo fazer o `INSERT` caso não atribua algum valor a essa *coluna*. Por que isso acontece?

Exemplo da tabela em questão:

```
CREATE TABLE `logs` (
  `id` int(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `host_name` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci;
```

Comment: Relacionado: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2296/101

Comment: Relacionado: [Null é igual a 'N'?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/87514/18246)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A *string* vazia é um **texto que possui zero caracteres**, mas é um texto.

O nulo é a **indeterminação de valor**. Nem um texto tem ali. Alguns acham que é ausência de valor, mas um nulo é um valor. E portanto não é nada também. Sabe quando tem uma pesquisa onde tem as opções "sim", "não" e "não quero responder". O nulo é mais um "não quero responder". Ainda que muitas vezes isso não deixa de ser uma terceira opção que talvez deva fazer parte do *roll* de valores aceitos*. Nulo é um valor, mas não um texto, que normalmente é o que se espera ali.

[image: Dois locais para papel higiênico, um rolo vazio e outro sem o rolo]

## Seu caso

A declaração da coluna `host_name` indica que ela não pode ter valor nulo, portanto precisa ter algum texto colocado, qualquer coisa serve, até mesmo um texto vazio.

Esse é um caso que parece adequado porque ficaria estranho não ter algo cadastrado aí. Claro que continua estranho permitir um texto vazio, ou algo que não se parece com um *hostname*. Então fico pensando: de que vale essa restrição se continua permitindo dados inválidos? Por outro lado validar *hostname* não é fácil porque ele aceita muita coisa. Se fosse [validar apenas domínios, aí tem RFC sobre isso](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1035). E se a aplicação validará isso, porque não deixar que tudo seja validado lá?

## Null ou não null, eis a questão

Há uma corrente que diz que o modelo relacional não deveria permitir nulos e que sempre é possível evitá-los com a modelagem adequada. É verdade, mas pragmaticamente nem sempre isso é o ideal. Pode complicar o modelo só para seguir essa regra. Claro que é bom pensar se pode evitar nulos sem complicações, só não torne isso uma obrigação.

O nulo não costuma fazer parte dos dados válidos e não costumam entrar em uma seleção, a não ser que determine explicitamente que isto deva ocorrer. Só não me lembro se isso ocorre por padrão no MySQL, ou se depende de alguma configuração (ou quem sabe `collate`, o que duvido).

## Espaço ocupado

Se estiver preocupado com o tamanho ocupado, é complicado e depende do mecanismo de armazenamento usado. Vou simplificar algumas coisas.

Em ambos o espaço ocupado se é nulo ou não, ou se é vazio ou não, é o mesmo.

#### MyISAM

Cada coluna anulável ocupará 1 bit no cabeçalho da linha. Obviamente que sempre haverá um preenchimento para alcançar 1 byte se tiver um número não divisível por 8 (tamanho do byte), ressaltando que há ainda 1 bit para indicar se a linha está deletada e entra nessa conta, portanto para até 7 colunas anuláveis, o custo é zero. Note que colunas `NOT NULL` não ocupam esse espaço, e o fato de ser nulo ou não, não altera o tamanho.

Uma coluna `varchar` sempre ocupa 2 bytes para indicar seu tamanho, portanto uma *string* vazia teria o valor 0 e não ocuparia outro espaço. Se for nulo ocorreria o mesmo, mas o banco de dados não consideraria o valor.

[Documentação](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/myisam-introduction.html).

#### InnoDB

Todas as colunas precisam de uma entrada no cabeçalho da linha de 1 ou 2 bytes (fixo para toda linha) para indicar seu tamanho e se é nulo ou não. Não importa se a coluna é anulável ou não. Toda coluna ocupará esse byte (dois se passar de 127) sempre.

Não há outro custo extra para um `varchar`.

[Documentação](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/innodb-field-start-offsets.html).

## Performance

Uma coluna tendo valor nulo pode ter um ligeiro ganho de performance em buscas em algumas circunstâncias, mas é bem mínimo.

## Relacionado

- [Quando devemos permitir que uma coluna de uma tabela de um banco de dados aceite NULL?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2296/101)
- [O que realmente significa NULL?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/90363/101)
- [Por que valores NULL não são selecionados?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/87514/101)

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 6):

Diferenças:

Tamanho que ocupa no banco:
A diferença é pífia, sendo que NULL ocuparia menos espaço, pois NULL é literalmente nada e uma string vazia, tem ao menos a informação de ser uma string.

Diferença no uso cotidiano com SQL:
A comparação com uma string vazia no SQL se utiliza de  um = , já a comparação com NULL se utiliza dos termos IS NULL ou IS NOT NULL.

Filosofia:
Um campo cujo preenchimento é necessário quando da criação da tabela será criado como NOT NULL. Antigamente caso não fosse inserido nada em um campo que foi definido como NOT NULL na criação da tabela então o banco tentava inserir um valor correspondente a vazio de acordo com o tipo de campo, strings eram "", números 0 ou 0.0, boolean era false, mas atualmente as novas versões de banco estão brecando essas inserções.

Diferença no código da programação:
A comparação de string vazia se dá com == , a comparação com NULL utiliza uma função da linguagem. No caso do php a função é is_null($variavel)