# Comparar NULL usando CASE SQL

Tags: sql, null, case

Tenho que recuperar 2 campos nessa query(número de projetos e a gerencia que executa tal projeto). Essa query vai ser usada para gerar um relatório no JASPER e este não exibe campo com valor `NULL`, por isso, quero que para cada `null` na coluna `f.br_nome_ger_executo` a consulta retorne "gerencia não informada". Essa query tá funcionando, mas exibe o `null` na resposta da consulta.

```
select  count(i.is_active) NUMERO_PROJETOS,
case f.br_nome_ger_executo
      when null then 'Gerencia nao informada'
      else f.br_nome_ger_executo end as GERENCIA_EXECUTORA
from inv_investments i
join odf_ca_project f on i.id = f.id  and i.is_active = 1
group by f.br_nome_ger_executo
```

Fiz um teste com a sigla de uma das gerencias e ele retorna o texto corretamente.

Agradeço a ajuda.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Para comparar um valor nulo você deve utilizá-lo no `WHEN` com `IS NULL`:

```
SELECT COUNT(i.is_active) AS NUMERO_PROJETOS,
       CASE
         WHEN f.br_nome_ger_executo IS NULL THEN 'Gerencia nao informada'
         ELSE f.br_nome_ger_executo
       END AS GERENCIA_EXECUTORA
  FROM inv_investments i
 INNER JOIN odf_ca_project f
    ON i.id = f.id
   and i.is_active = 1
 GROUP BY f.br_nome_ger_executo
```

Uma outra forma de ter o resultado desejado é utilizar a função `ISNULL`:

```
SELECT COUNT(i.is_active) AS NUMERO_PROJETOS,
       ISNULL(f.br_nome_ger_executo, 'Gerencia nao informada') AS GERENCIA_EXECUTORA
  FROM inv_investments i
 INNER JOIN odf_ca_project f
    ON i.id = f.id
   AND i.is_active = 1
 GROUP BY f.br_nome_ger_executo
```

> [ISNULL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms184325.aspx)
>
> Substitui NULL pelo valor de substituição especificado.

---

Aqui você confere uma breve explicação do motivo pelo qual a solução inicial não funcionava: [**Por que valores NULL não são selecionados?**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/87518/59479)

Comment: Funcionou ! Muito obrigado. SOu estagiário há um mês apenas e cheguei a usar o is null de diversas formas e dava um erro de "from não encontrada, fora do lugar". Tanto que peguei esse primeiro código meio desacreditado. Pq esse pegou e o meu não ? haha 
Colocar as palavras reservadas do sql em caixa alta pode ter relação ?
Muito obrigado.

Comment: @JesséPereira fico feliz que a resposta tenha lhe ajudado. Não esqueça de marcar a resposta como escolhida no "V" verde. Quanto ao case das palavras, depende do collation do seu banco, mas geralmente no SQL Server não faz diferença

Comment: Essa função ISNULL existe no oracle? 
Deu um google e vi apenas no mysql e sql server.

Comment: @JesséPereira no Oracle não existe `ISNULL`, mas você pode substituir por `COALESCE`, que possui o mesmo principio porém pode receber mais de dois parâmetros e retorna o primeiro não-nulo