# Por que "= NULL" não funciona?

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, sql-server, query, select

No `SQL Server`, ao buscar todos os registros com determinado campo com valor `NULL`, se eu fizer da seguinte forma nenhum registro é retornado:

```
SELECT *
  FROM clientes cli
 WHERE cli.cpf = NULL
```

Porém se utilizar a seguinte sintaxe:

```
SELECT *
  FROM clientes cli
 WHERE cli.cpf IS NULL
```

Os registros corretos são retornados. Por que? E qual a diferença entre `= NULL` e `IS NULL`?

Comment: Null é ausência de informação , nada pode ser igual a null nem mesmo null , a síntaxe correta é IS NULL , se A é null e B é null A=B retorna false por exemplo.

Comment: relacionada https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/87514/null-%C3%A9-igual-a-n

Comment: O resultado depende da configuração de ANSI_NULLS

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Quando você faz a comparação `cli.cpf = NULL` o `=` serve para comparar valores, e `NULL` não é um valor. `NULL` é um espaço reservado para indicar a ausência de valor, é por isso que neste caso deve-se utilizar os predicados `IS NULL` ou `IS NOT NULL`.

Comment: só para complementar, no caso de update, aí sim, se coloca coluna = null, ex: update tabela set coluna = null, para que desta forma o campo fique null, não esquecendo as configurações da tabela, é claro.

Comment: @Groot não confunda comparação com associação. `Update tabela set campo2=null where campo1 is null`. O AP faz referência à comparação e não associação.

Answer (score 11):

A comparação

```
WHERE cli.cpf = NULL
```

é válida, desde que ANSI_NULLS esteja configurado como OFF.

Conforme consta na documentação de ANSI_NULLS, *Quando SET ANSI_NULLS for OFF, os operadores de comparação Igual a (=) e Diferente de (<>) não seguem o padrão ISO. Uma instrução SELECT que usa WHERE column_name = NULL retorna as linhas com valores nulos em column_name. Uma instrução SELECT que usa WHERE column_name <> NULL retorna as linhas com valores não nulos na coluna. Além disso, uma instrução SELECT que usa WHERE column_name <> XYZ_value retorna todas as linhas que não são XYZ_value e que não são nulos*.

```
-- código #1
set ANSI_NULLS ON;
SELECT colunas
  FROM clientes cli
  WHERE cli.cpf = NULL;

SELECT colunas
  FROM clientes cli
  WHERE cli.cpf is NULL;
```

e

```
-- código #2
set ANSI_NULLS OFF;
SELECT colunas
  FROM clientes cli
  WHERE cli.cpf = NULL;

SELECT colunas
  FROM clientes cli
  WHERE cli.cpf is NULL;
```

Entretanto, recomendo utilizar sempre a forma IS NULL e manter ANSI_NULLS como ON.

Documentação:

- [SET ANSI_NULLS](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-ansi-nulls-transact-sql)

Comment: De acordo com a documentação o `ANSI_NULLS` vai ser sempre `ON` após alguma versão futura... Entretando, boa resposta

Comment: @Sorack: essa observação está lá (no mínimo) desde a versão 2005 do SQL Server!  *rs* // Vide https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms188048(v=sql.90).aspx //

Answer (score 8):

O `NULL` é o indefinido e o indeterminado. Ele não é falso, mas também não é verdadeiro. Ele não é um valor, porém a falta de um. Por não ser um valor, ele pode ser considerado um **estado**. Um estado de indefinido.

> Um valor especial, ou uma marca, para indicar a falta de qualquer valor [(SQL-92)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL-92)

No SQL, até mesmo a comparação `NULL = NULL` é falsa. Veja os exemplos:

```
SELECT NULL = 0    // => false
SELECT NULL != 0   // => false
SELECT NULL = NULL // => false
```

Tudo que se comparar a `NULL` é falso, pois não é possível afirmar que é verdadeiro. E é daí que vem o operador `IS NULL`. Tendo como exemplo uma tabela de pessoas, vamos fazer algumas perguntas.

```
+----+-------+-------+
| ID | Nome  | Idade |
+----+-------+-------+
|  1 | João  | NULL  |
|  2 | Maria | 19    |
|  3 | José  | NULL  |
+----+-------+-------+
```

1. Quantos anos Maria tem? `19`
2. Quantos anos João tem? `NULL` - ou seja, não sei
3. Maria e João tem a mesma idade? `19 = NULL` - não posso afirmar, pois não sei a idade de João
4. João e José tem a mesma idade? `NULL = NULL` - não posso afirmar, pois não sei a idade deles

É por esse motivo que as comparações com  `NULL` precisam de um tratamento especial.

Comment: Ótimo exemplo +1

Comment: A introdução foi digna do Mestre Programador, das resposta do Ono Sendai