# Dúvida em Perfomance no SQL

Tags: sql

Uma dúvida que surgiu agora, e que sempre vejo de uma forma ou outra em SQLs de procedures, é o seguinte: `NOT TABELA.CAMPO IS NULL` ou `TABELA.CAMPO IS NOT NULL`. Qual a diferença na prática em questões de perfomance, tempo de execução, de um para o outro? A perfomance seria afetada, dependendo da quantidade de registros da tabela e/ou existência do index no campo?

Comment: Relacionado: [Por que valores NULL não são selecionados?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/87514/por-que-valores-null-n%C3%A3o-s%C3%A3o-selecionados)

Comment: Na questão de indexação da tabela: Por padrão, os bancos de dados relacionais ignoram os valores NULL (porque o modelo relacional diz que NULL significa "não presente"). Portanto, o índice não armazena valor NULL, conseqüentemente se você tem condição nula na instrução SQL, o índice relacionado é ignorado (por padrão).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não há diferença de performance mensurável. Ambas as formas são compiladas e otimizadas para a mesma representação interna por qualquer SGBD moderno, tendo então o mesmo desempenho.

Comment: Vi que se houver mais de um argumento há diferença, no caso: `NOT (val1, val2) IS NULL`  você recebe `true` se qualquer um dos valores forem nulo, mas eu não consegui reproduzir no *sql server*, talvez em outro *SGBD* seja assim, fonte: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4074619/7558069