# Comportamento do "NOT IN" afetando exibição de coluna com valor NULL

Tags: mysql

Eu tenho uma tabela onde eu registro as compras feitas pelo site.

Eu uso um campo chamado `status_plataforma` para receber os status da transação do PagSeguro. Esse campo, além de poder receber um inteiro, por padrão ele é `NULL`.

Em uma determinada consulta, eu precisava saber se o campo `status_plataforma` **não está** com o valor `6` ou `7`. Para isso, eu estou usando a condição `WHERE status_plataforma NOT IN(6, 7)`.
Porém, quando esse campo está com o valor `NULL`, o resultado não é encontrado!

Ou seja, não tenho `6` nem `7` nessa coluna, mas apenas `NULL` e, teoricamente, deveria ser retornado o resultado.

**Meus Testes:**

Exemplo sem `NOT IN`:

```
mysql> select id, preco, status_plataforma, concluida  FROM compras WHERE site_cadastro_aluno_id = 43;
+----+-------+-------------------+-----------+
| id | preco | status_plataforma | concluida |
+----+-------+-------------------+-----------+
| 41 | 29.90 | NULL              |         0 |
+----+-------+-------------------+-----------+
1 row in set (0,00 sec)
```

O problema acontece quando uso `NOT IN`:

```
mysql> select id, preco, status_plataforma, concluida  FROM compras WHERE site_cadastro_aluno_id = 43 AND status_plataforma NOT IN (6,7);
Empty set (0,00 sec)
```

Como se vê na consulta anterior, de fato `status_plataforma` não é nem `6` nem `7`, mas sim `NULL`.

Por que o `NOT IN` teve esse comportamento?

Comment: Relacionada: [Por que valores NULL não são selecionados?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/87514/por-que-valores-null-n%C3%A3o-s%C3%A3o-selecionados)

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Por que valores NULL não são selecionados?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/87514/por-que-valores-null-n%c3%a3o-s%c3%a3o-selecionados)

Comment: Não sei quem marcou como duplicada, mas não vejo relação com o problema do `NOT IN`

Comment: @WallaceMaxters foi eu. É o mesmo problema. Não tem nem como fazer uma nova resposta, seria uma cópia.

Comment: `AND (status_plataforma NOT IN (6,7) OR status_plataforma IS NULL)`

Comment: SQL Server e Mysql teria o mesmo comportamento?

Comment: @WallaceMaxters sim!

Comment: Fiz em cima do [SQLFiddle em SQL Server](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/d1b63/5) do Maniero: [SQLFiddle em MySQL](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/14db2a/3)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assim como discutido em [Por que valores NULL não são selecionados?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/87514/5878), `NULL` não é um valor, então não há como compará-lo com outros valores - inclusive com ele mesmo.

Por exemplo, mesmo que você fizesse

```
select id, preco, status_plataforma, concluida FROM compras WHERE status_plataforma = NULL;
```

Não haveria resultados, pois como comentado, não há como comparar algo com `NULL`.

Para contornar o *problema*, você tem duas opções:

1. Adicionar a condição `OR status_plataforma IS NULL`, ficando:

   ```
   SELECT id, preco, status_plataforma, concluida FROM compras WHERE site_cadastro_aluno_id = 43 AND (status_plataforma NOT IN (6,7) OR status_plataforma IS NULL);
   ```
2. Utilizar a função [`coalesce`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce) para *forçar* um valor caso seja nulo - só tomar cuidado para que este valor não esteja na lista indicada:

   ```
   SELECT id, preco, status_plataforma, concluida FROM compras WHERE site_cadastro_aluno_id = 43 AND COALESCE(status_plataforma, 0) NOT IN (6,7);
   ```

No segundo caso, se a coluna for nula, ela passará a ser avaliada como 0, e, portanto, o registro será selecionado visto que 0 não pertence a (6, 7).

Comment: Não conhecia esse `COALESCE`! Muito útil!  +1

Comment: @rbz ele aceita inúmeros argumentos e retorna sempre o primeiro não nulo. Nesse caso é *meio gambiarra*, mas aceitável visto que a lista é conhecida e garantido que 0 nunca fará parte dela. Se a lista for dinâmica, não tem como garantir isso e não daria para utilizá-la.

Comment: Entendi! É que já tive vários casos que usei o `CASE` e poderia usar tranquilamente esse `COALESCE`. 