# Mostrar valores NULL SQL

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, sql-server

Boa noite, sou novo em SQL e tenho uma dúvida.

Tenho a seguinte base de dados:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O meu objectivo é apresentar o nome dos funcionários, a sua função e o nome do departamento onde trabalham tendo que estar o resultado ordenado pelo nome do departamento e dentro do departamento pelo nome do empregado. No entanto é-me pedido para apresentar o nome do departamento onde não trabalha ninguém, tendo o resultado de ser igual à seguinte imagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Sem a parte do NULL eu sei que o código seria:

```
select emp.nome, emp.funcao, dep.nome 
from emp, dep 
where emp.ndep = dep.ndep
order by dep.nome, emp.nome;
```

No entanto não consigo arranjar forma de incluir o NULL na tabela, já experimentei usar o IS NULL mas dá-me erro, provavelmente porque o estou a usar mal. Alguém me consegue dar uma ajuda?

Obrigado

Comment: [Por que valores NULL não são selecionados?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/87514/por-que-valores-null-n%C3%A3o-s%C3%A3o-selecionados)

Comment: Como assim? Não estou a perceber a pergunta

Comment: João veja as respostas.

Comment: Entender a [diferença de INNER JOIN e OUTER JOIN](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/6441/70) pode te ajudar a trazer nulos em uma resposta

Comment: Faça a leitura que o @Bacco comentou e depois tente fazer o join usando um `left join` por exemplo, que permite trazer valores de uma tabela mesmo que não haja valor ligando na outra tabela

Answer (score 0):

Ola,

Voce pode utilizar o left join:

```
SELECT * FROM [emp] AS [e] 
LEFT JOIN [dep] AS [d] ON e.ndep = d.ndep
order by [d].nome, [e].nome;
```