# Parâmetros Stored Procedures

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

Estou com uma dúvida e queria pedir a ajuda de vocês. Seguinte: tenho uma `proc` e quero que quando eu não passar um parâmetro ela me retorne `null` e quando isso acontecer trazer a data do dia  -1 e hora zerada e se for passado parâmetro execute normal segue como eu estava fazendo.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Dbo.AtualizaTMP_Venda(
    @IdContrato INT = 1 
) 
    AS

IF @IdContrato = NULL
    BEGIN
    SELECT CAST(CAST(GETDATE() -1 AS DATE) AS DATETIME)
    END
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você deve fazer a verificação o `NULL` com o `IS` ao invés de `=` (O motivo você pode conferir na resposta da pergunta ["Por que valores NULL não são selecionados?"](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/87518/59479). Depois disso você deve usar a função [`DATEADD`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms186819(v=sql.120).aspx) para retornar a data atual -1 dia:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Dbo.AtualizaTMP_Venda(
  @IdContrato INT = NULL
) AS
BEGIN
  IF @IdContrato IS NULL
  BEGIN
    SELECT DATEADD(DAY, -1, GETDATE()) AS data;

    RETURN;
  END;
  
  -- Continua a execução normal
END;
GO
```

---

> [`DATEADD`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms186819(v=sql.120).aspx)
>
> Retorna uma data especificada com o intervalo numérico especificado (inteiro assinado) adicionado à parte da data especificada.

Comment: Muito Obrigado, Deu Certinho :)